Centralized auditd Server doesn't works on Ubuntu
I’m trying to set up a centralized auditd server to collect logs from multiple machines. The setup works fine on other Linux distributions like CentOS and Debian, but I’m encountering an issue when setting it up on an Ubuntu-based centralized auditd server. I’m seeing the following error messages in the auditd (auditd -f) debug log:
tcp_listen_port_parser called with: 60
Listener support is not enabled, ignoring value at line 27
tcp_listen_queue_parser called with: 5
Listener support is not enabled, ignoring value at line 28
tcp_max_per_addr_parser called with: 1
Listener support is not enabled, ignoring value at line 29
tcp_client_max_idle_parser called with: 0
Listener support is not enabled, ignoring value at line 31
transport_parser called with: TCP

Configuration:

Server Configuration: On the Ubuntu centralized auditd server, I’ve configured the tcp_listen_port in the /etc/audit/auditd.conf file to accept incoming logs on the specified TCP port.
Client Configuration: On the Debian client machines, I’ve configured the remote machine details in the /etc/audit/audisp-remote.conf file and set the "active" parameter to yes in the /etc/audit/plugins.d/au-remote.conf file to enable forwarding logs to the central server.
Firewall Settings: I’ve verified the firewall settings on both the client and the server, ensuring that the necessary port (TCP 60) for remote logging is open on both ends.

Question:

Why is the TCP port not opening on the centralized auditd server, and is there any reason why Ubuntu doesn't support centralized auditd while it works on other distributions like Debian and CentOS?

Any help or advice on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your assistance!

any help in this DEV article

Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/787595/centralized-auditd-server-doesnt-works-on-ubuntu
